# localStorage key not being stored

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I am trying to store a key on both the current page, and an external page. In the example below I use google.

```
window.localStorage.setItem(url, x);
var url2 = "http://google.com/";
document.location = url2;
storeToDB(url, x);


function storeToDB(url, x) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log("Waiting..."); }, 1000); 
    window.localStorage.setItem(url, x);
    document.location = url;
    console.log("Value Stored");
}
```

The method is called, however, the key is not stored.
Why?

This code is running on a content-script on a chrome-extension.

Comment: where from the `url` is coming at very first line `window.localStorage.setItem(url, x);`?

Comment: There's more to the function above it. It's defined.

Comment: Please add the code the initialize variables `url` and `x`.

Answer (score -1):

You are using location property in document, but location is a window property. And also when you store your data using localStorage you have to name a key in the firstpart of the setItem method. For example:

```
localStorage.setItem('key','data');
```

But you used variables. And you didnot store any data in that variables.
Without '' it accept as a variable.